# ViZDoomErrorException: Could not initialize SDL video

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/simoninithomas/Deep_reinforcement_learning_Course/blob/master/Policy%20Gradients/Doom/Doom%20REINFORCE%20Monte%20Carlo%20Policy%20gradients.ipynb) using Google Colab.

When I run the line `game.init()`, I get this error:

```
ViZDoomErrorException: Could not initialize SDL video:
No available video device
```

I installed `vizdoom` as follows:

```
%%bash
# Install deps from 
# https://github.com/mwydmuch/ViZDoom/blob/master/doc/Building.md#-linux

apt-get install build-essential zlib1g-dev libsdl2-dev libjpeg-dev \
nasm tar libbz2-dev libgtk2.0-dev cmake git libfluidsynth-dev libgme-dev \
libopenal-dev timidity libwildmidi-dev unzip

# Boost libraries
apt-get install libboost-all-dev

# Lua binding dependencies
apt-get install liblua5.1-dev
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colab is run on a machine in the cloud. It cannot send the display back to your local machine. That's why it said "no video device".

Comment: Is there any workaround? Or does it mean that I should use local Jupiter notebook without Colab?

Comment: You can try Colab with local runtime.

Comment: Make sure you have "game.set_window_visible(False)" just before "game.init()". Then you can use colab!

Answer (score 2):

Add the line `game.set_window_visible(False)` in the Step 8 cell of the Jupyter Notebook. Unless explicitly mentioned, ViZDoom tries to launch the application, which is not supported in Colab.